# Does Platform Event / CDC uses same Async queue as Queueable/ Future?

Tags: apex, platform-event, asynchronous, change-data-capture

We have a huge concurrent influx of incoming custom api requests. (1000+ under 5 seconds approx)
Because of this we were getting `ConcurrentPerOrgLongTxn Limit exceeded.`

We moved from Sync processing in Custom web service to Async processing. i.e we used `System.enqueueJob` to process the request asynchronously, assuming the processing would take max 1 second.

From past few days a huge influx of events started coming to our custom webservice, and our `System.enqueueJob` gets fired, but the requests goes in `Queued` status, We can see after running this SOQL

`SELECT COUNT() FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Status = 'Queued'`
Some 70K records are in `Queued` status and only 3-4 in `Processing` status.

Not sure of the reason though. But we are planning to move to Platform Events or CDC instead of `System.enqueueJob`, and then have an Async Trigger for CDC or Listen to Platform Events from trigger and then process the incoming requests.

My question is "Does CDC/Platform Event uses the same Async Queue which `System.enqueueJob` (Queueable) uses?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll see that [AsyncApexJob](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_asyncapexjob.htm) lists out what mechanisms use it

> Represents an individual Apex sharing recalculation job, a batch Apex job, a method with the future annotation, or a job that implements Queueable

Platform events do not use the same "queue" as Phil answered and have their own, [separate limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.234.0.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_event_limits.htm) to consider and track with the [services/data/v54.0/limits](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm) endpoint

- HourlyPublishedPlatformEvents

  - *High-volume platform event notifications published per hour*
- MonthlyPlatformEvents

  - *If your org doesn’t have the high-volume platform event or Change Data Capture add-on*. *Includes usage for both high-volume platform events and Change Data Capture events.*
- MonthlyPlatformEventsUsageEntitlement

  - *If your org has the high-volume platform event or Change Data Capture add-on.*  *This value includes usage for both high-volume platform events and Change Data Capture events.*

Important to note that Change Data Capture (CDC) "change events" are specialized platform events. As such, the [allocations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.change_data_capture.meta/change_data_capture/cdc_allocations.htm#:%7E:text=The%20maximum%20event%20message%20size,you%20can%20reach%20this%20limit.) for CDC (and platform events above) are shared when it comes to *event delivery* and why some of the above contains delivery information for both combined.

> Change events are based on platform events. The default allocations and usage-based entitlement of delivered events are shared between change events and high-volume platform events.

[Monitor Platform Event Publishing and Delivery Usage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_monitor_usage.htm) goes over how the REST limits endpoint provides info on both CDC & Platform Events delivery - but, there's a [PlatformEventusageMetric](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_platformeventusagemetric.htm) which allows getting usage with a distinction between the two.

> The usage metrics stored in PlatformEventUsageMetric are separate from the REST API limits values. Use the REST API limits to track your monthly delivery and publishing usage against your allocations. The monthly CometD-client delivery usage that the limits API returns is common for platform events and change data capture events. PlatformEventUsageMetric breaks down usage of platform events and change data capture events so you can track their usage separately.

---

In terms of what does it use if it's not using AsyncApexJob - the [Considerations for Publishing Platform Events](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_considerations.htm) goes into some details on what it's doing

> Platform events are temporarily persisted to and served from an industry-standard distributed system during the retention period. A distributed system doesn’t have the same semantics or guarantees as a transactional database. As a result, we can’t provide a synchronous response for an event publish request. Events are queued and buffered, and Salesforce attempts to publish the events asynchronously. In rare cases, the event message might not be persisted in the distributed system during the initial or subsequent attempts. This means that the events aren’t delivered to subscribers, and they aren’t recoverable.

Since you seem most interested in subscribing through Apex Triggers - [Subscribe to Platform Event Notifications with Apex Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_apex.htm) covers that area

> An Apex trigger **processes platform event notifications sequentially** in the order they’re received. The order of events is based on the event replay ID. **An Apex trigger can receive a batch of events at once**. The maximum batch size in a platform event trigger is 2,000 event messages. The order of events is preserved within each batch. The events in a batch can originate from one or more publishers.

> Unlike triggers on standard or custom objects, triggers on platform events don’t execute in the same Apex transaction as the one that published the event. **The trigger runs asynchronously in its own process. As a result, there can be a delay between when an event is published and when the trigger processes the event.**

Comment: HourlyPublishedPlatformEvents and MonthlyPlatformEvents I believe only applies to Platform Events and not CDC. Right?

Comment: The default allocations & usage-based entitlements of delivered events are shared between the two. I'll update the answer

Comment: In documentation there is no limits mentioned for Publishing CDC, but publishing PE has a limit as per documentation. So there shouldn’t be any limits to CDC fired in 1 hour or montly.

Comment: You're correct for `HourlyPublishedPlatformEvents` (just contains info for Platform Events) - but `MonthlyPlatformEvents` is different and is what I was commenting on - [limits endpoint](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_limits.htm): "This value contains the default allocation and usage for event delivery to CometD clients and is incremented for each client. MonthlyPlatformEvents includes usage for both high-volume platform events and Change Data Capture events".

Comment: One of the problems I have with the way the documentation frames the execution as "async" is that the platform considers then as synchronous, from the limits perspective. The documentation authors completely failed to consider this. That is why I frame it as "synchronous" in a decoupled transaction (or "process" as this documentation oddly calls it) where the (distributed, in-memory) queue provides that decoupling, and the "queue consumer" processes the invocations for trigger and CometD subscribers. I imagine the "queue" tech is something like IBM MQ, Oracle AQ or similar.

Comment: @KrisGoncalves even `MonthlyPlatformEvents` is for delivery to CometD clients. What I was saying is there is no limit to publish CDC.

Comment: @PhilW Yes you are correct, these actually have only Sync limits. But CDC being a queue based tech, should work as async trigger. So it should not work as FIFO. If we are listening to CDC via a Trigger. It should process multiple requests concurrently or parallelly.

Comment: Yes, I was just focused on event delivery. In the CDC allocation doc I linked it mentions why there's no limit to publish. "Salesforce publishes change events in response to record changes, so doesn’t enforce a publishing limit for Change Data Capture because users don’t control the total events published."

Comment: CDC is a specialist PE with different limits - you are limited on numbers of types of object you can CDC against on the org rather than directly on numbers of events per 24 hours, for example. While not all queue technologies always enforce FIFO many do. However unless the documentation tells you what the behaviour is, Salesforce can in principle chose to change it at any time.

Answer (score 3):

> Does CDC/Platform Event uses the same Async Queue which System.enqueueJob (Queueable) uses?

No. Platform Events are not actually async executions; they are essentially synchronous executions **in a separate transaction**, where the decoupling is via use of an "event queue" of some kind.

One of the problems I have with the way the documentation frames the execution as "async" is that the platform considers then as synchronous, from the limits perspective. The documentation authors completely failed to consider this aspect.

That is why I frame it as "synchronous" in a decoupled transaction where the (distributed, in-memory) queue provides that decoupling, and the "queue consumer" processes the invocations for trigger and CometD subscribers.

My understanding is that this "event queue" does not persist in the database, which is how come delivery is not guaranteed - the queue is in-memory and thus could get lost if the server/cluster dies. (I imagine the "queue" tech is something like IBM MQ, Oracle AQ or similar but have no actual knowledge of this.)

Importantly, if a behaviour is not explicitly documented by Salesforce they can, in principle, choose to change it at any time. I would therefore say you probably don't want to rely on whether multiple trigger-based subscribers run sequentially or in parallel since as far as I know this is not documented. (Kris Goncalves's answer nicely links to the official documentation available.)

Comment: Ok understood,  so even here it will enter an `event queue` if a huge influx is there and the processing might be delayed.  As event queue should work in fifo manner. Just last follow up question. Can the platform event trigger listener process requests concurrently or one by one.

Comment: Not sure I understand "trigger listener process requests"? Do you mean "are the events sent to multiple subscribers concurrently"? If so, I don't actually know; I've not tried to analyse that behaviour.

Comment: That means platform event are being listened via trigger. So can trigger process request in parallel . Or will they process it one by one.

Comment: So, that's what I call an "trigger-based event subscriber"; you subscribe to platform events either using apex triggers or using cometD. As I mentioned, I didn't analyse the behaviour when there are multiple subscribers (trigger or cometD based). You would need an actual Salesforce R&D dev to confirm. Sorry.